# How to implement cron job for docker-compose env

Tags: docker, cron, docker-compose

I have two dockerized services, the question is what is the best practice to do cron job for that services using the 3rd container (like cron container). It sounds like a bad idea, but I need to involve cron. It shouldn't be docker's host cron. Or maybe there is another appropriate way to implement such a job I don't know about. Please help, mates!

Comment: https://crontab.guru/

Comment: You can run a dedicated cron container; the problem is getting it access to whatever things you need to run in other containers.  Making it able to `docker run` Or `docker exec` things gives it unrestricted root-level access over the whole host.

Comment: What would you recommend, should I use Docker host's cron? I'm not happy about that idea because I'm afraid it won't work from the box. I need something like running $> ```docker-compose up -d``` and that's it. No any user's activity at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crontab fields from left to right are:

- minute
- hour
- day (month)
- month
- day (week)

So, you can add a crontab job with the following:

`crontab -u root -e`

`5 * * * *   sh  your_script;`

Comment: I have two dockerized services, the question is what is the best practice to do cron job for that services using the 3rd container (like cron container). It sounds like a bad idea, but I need to involve cron. It shouldn't be docker's host cron. Or maybe there is another appropriate way to implement such a job I don't know about. Please help, mates!

Comment: (Noting that this is a valid answer to the question you originally asked, “how do I write the crontab?”.)